# Hide elements after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

Using jquery, when I click on `Search from documents` I want to hide all `li` elements which have an `aria-label` that contains `COMPANY` in the vlaue. here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none; top: 30px; left: 0px; width: 236px;">
    <li class="search-documents-btn ui-menu-item" aria-label=" Search from documents &amp;raquo;" id="ui-id-111" tabindex="-1">
        Search from documents »
    </li>
    <li class="search-category ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-112" tabindex="-1">
        Companies
    </li>
    <li aria-label="test" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-113" tabindex="-1">

    </li>
    <li aria-label="test1" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-114" tabindex="-1">

    </li>
    <li class="search-category ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-122" tabindex="-1">
        Branches
    </li>
    <li aria-label="test2" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-127" tabindex="-1">

    </li>
    <li aria-label="test3" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-128" tabindex="-1">

    </li>
</ul>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to hide the elements which contain a 'Company page' `a` element, or the `li` elements that have an `aria-label` containing the word `COMPANY`?

Comment: the elements which have aria-label COMPANY

Comment: I've added an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to hide all the elements that have an `aria-label` that contains `COMPANY`. Try this:

```
$('#ui-id-111').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr('aria-label').indexOf('COMPANY') != -1;
    }).hide();
});
```

Comment: can you also show me how to filter on both company and branch elements?

Comment: To filter on branch, just change the string you give to the `indexOf()` function.

Comment: `$(this).closest('ul').find('li').filter("[aria-label*=BRANCH],[aria-label*=COMPANY]").hide();` this solution is another option

Comment: Actually after little refactor both code works :) thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo-selector.

> Select all elements that contain the specified text.

See the comments inline in the code:

```
// On click of the button
$('#ui-id-111').on('click', function() {
    $('li:contains("Company")').hide();
    // Hide all the li's that are containing `Company` as their innerText
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5auvfpwc/)