# hide element by attribute value and text contain

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the button I want to hide elements which either has `Val` as text or attribute value. Basically what I want is after clicking search for documents button I send new request to server and I want to hide every element containing `branch` or `company`

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <li class="search-documents-btn ui-menu-item">
        Search from documents »
    </li>
    <li class="search-category ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-112" tabindex="-1">
        Companies
    </li>
    <li aria-label="COMPANY : AUTO EDIBUYER" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-113" tabindex="-1">
        AUTO EDIBUYER
    </li>
    <li aria-label="COMPANY : AUTO EDISUPPLIER" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-114" tabindex="-1">
        AUTO EDISUPPLIER
    </li>
    <li class="search-category ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-122" tabindex="-1">
        Branches
    </li>
    <li aria-label="BRANCH : AUTO WEBSUPPLIER 4DOC" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-127" tabindex="-1">
        AUTO WEBSUPPLIER 4DOC
    </li>
    <li aria-label="BRANCH : AutoTest" class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-128" tabindex="-1">
        AutoTest
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add your complete code

Comment: Please add what you tried for this

Comment: I'm confused as `Val` does not appear anywhere in your HTML...?

Comment: I tried this line of code but it doesn't work `$('li:contains("Company"), li:contains("Branch")').hide();`

Comment: val is just an example :)

Comment: Ok, so how is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069599/hide-elements-after-clicking-a-button) which already has an answer which will achieve what you require here?

Comment: I thought it worked but it doesn't and I don't know how to do it in different way so if someone has any suggestion please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use attribute contains

```
$( "li[aria-label*='COMPANY']" ).hide();
$( "li:contains('Branches')" ).hide();
$( "li:contains('Companies')" ).hide();
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j05yaor1/1/)

Comment: I want also to hide Companies and Branches elements

Comment: @user3478286 does this accomplish what you are looking to do ?